# The Rise of Nudism: Consequences and Prerequisites

Tags: society, culture, politics

The year is 20xx and through some opportunistic series of social events (see (3) below) people have become more aware of the nature and aims of the nudism movement, and in particular, a larger fraction of the population would be inclined toward nudism were it not for legal and social prohibitions. Given the very unique status of nudity and of nudism in society, I ask the following interrelated questions:

1. In democratic societies currently outlawing generic public nudity, what would the opinionated social climate need to look like before a legislative body would pass a law defending nudists from prosecution in the general public? Would the sympathizers need to be merely a sizable minority, a fair majority, or a nigh-unanimity? Would there need to be fervent contribution/pressure from nudist lobbies before such a law would even be considered?
2. Following the dissolution of legal sanctions, what would be the social consequences of the change? Particularly, how quickly would public acceptance of nudism rise, and to what level, presuming from the start that citizens exercised their new liberty frequently? Which stigmas would all but vanish within a generation, and which would stick around a while? If, say, a large modern Western country suddenly went truly nude blind*, would it entail (either by logical hypothesis or by material consequence) a very potent effect on other countries?
3. What would be some sufficient conditions/events to promulgate the rise of a modern, truly nude-blind society?

Clarifications:

- "Nude blind" of course not meaning some requirement or bias toward being in the nude in any given circumstance, but describing a society in which the decision to wear clothes at any time is dependent only on their basic sensual/survival utility (warmth, protection, comfort), and *some* social considerations; gym shorts aren't discriminated in the modern day, but I wouldn't wear them to an interview!
- To my knowledge, many European regions and some notable US locations ([San Francisco?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_social_nudity_places_in_North_America#California)) allow social nudity, even where it isn't the main tourist attraction. However, in the current scenario we are focusing on the blanket lifting of social restrictions across a society where the populace is keenly interested in the result, so that **current statuses and developments will be highly publicized.** Of course, however, you will probably find it necessary to differentiate or restrict the content of your response to particular countries.
- I'm not particularly interested in the differences between nudism and naturism. If circumstances appeal to an adoption of naturism merely implying a type of nudism, so be it.

As a social phenomenon, I'd like to compare this hypothetical event with the actual rise of LGBT rights and awareness in the 20th century. In little more than half a century, sodomy laws in many modern countries went from routine enforcers of decency to bygone discriminatory practices. As it concerns the objective nature of social revolutions, how is this comparison accurate or inaccurate?

Comment: Welcomd to Worldbuilding SE, Feryll. Those are many questions at once. It is usually not a good strategy, as people will tend to skip some in their answers. Furthermore, your second point looks awfully broad. I would recommend to consider a series of question instead. Maybe focus on the legal part (point 1) for this one, and after some time ask another question for the following step.

Comment: There is short manga comic (NSFW) called Ragnarock City where due to heavy cybernetization people started value real flesh so they began to show it more and more to the point of being practically nude.

Answer (score 0):

In *purely* democratic nations (government of the cattle, by the cattle, for the cattle), laws usually get passed when:

1- the majority of population agrees on one thing and makes it the norm

2- a sizable minority demands something that does not breach the rights of the majority, in which case they are *allowed* to practice their customs (the best example is the recent legalization of gay marriages)

3- this is a matter of personal choice e.g. some western countries had a ban on Muslim women covering their faces up. This has been lately annulled in most of the countries due to being a breach of individual freedom

In order to *allow* nudity in public places, you will have to get a sizable minority.

Public acceptance is a very opinion based matter. Different nations have different *ethical* and social codes of conduct. Mostly the Europeans are more open minded towards nudity than Americans or Asians. African communities are also more open to the idea. There is no universal formula on this matter. In some countries in might be immediately accepted while in others, it might never become a norm.

The conditions and prerequisites are also very opinion based, I would say. Assuming none of the members here has had a detailed research focused on nudism in their doctorate thesis, everyone would have their own personal opinions. I don't think this is a very constructive thing to ask.